# Python Network Programming on Linux - Simultaneous use of two network interface on the client?

Tags: python, networking, interface

Currently I have two network interfaces on my client. I created two separate sockets which binds to each interface ip. Now I also have two servers with each one talking to one socket on the client. I want to be able to receive data (~10MB for now but will be larger later) from both interfaces simultaneously (currently using UDP or DGRAMS) but for some reason there is always a delay in that it has to finish the data transfer with one socket before it begins the transfer on the other socket.

I have confirmed that binding each interface is successful and I am able to communicate on each socket with its respective server. Currently I simply execute `s1.recv()` and `s2.recv()` within the same code block.

So my question is that, is the delay due to the "blocking" feature of using `recv()`? Also through my search it seems there are ways to make the function to be unblocking? But I am not certain how to go about doing that... And would this be resolved by using multithreading? I am a bit rusty with multithread but if it resolves my issue I will look into it. If not then how can I utilize both interfaces in that I am able to receive/send from both interfaces in parallel?

If anyone can assist I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The `recv` function is blocking by default. This means that the method will halt the control flow, until something is received on this socket. If you call `sock1.recv()` and then `sock2.recv()`, the second call will only be reached when socket 1  receives something.

You can use the `setblocking` method to make `recv` non-blocking, causing it to return at once, even if there is nothing to receive. However, then you would probably have to poll both sockets for new bytes to read:

```
s1.setblocking(False)
s2.setblocking(False)

while True:
    # In non-blocking mode, recv throws a socket.error when
    # there is nothing to receive.
    try: a = s1.recv()
    except socket.error: a = None

    try: b = s2.recv()
    except socket.error: b = None

    handle_data(a,b) # Use received bytes at your discretion
```

You could parallelize the two `recv` calls, using either the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) or [`threading`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) modules:

```
class SocketThread(threading.Thread):
    def run():
        while True:
            a = self.sock.recv() # This time, recv in blocking mode
            handle_data(a)

t1, t2 = SocketThread(), SocketThread()
t1.sock = sock1
t1.start()

t2.sock = sock2
t2.start()
```

Comment: You forgot to mention Twisted, which will do the hard part of this for you. :)

Comment: I didn't know about Twisted, but it looks very interesting. Thank you for the tip! :)